# 16th century French Bible compilation

Tags: xetex

How should the tex file for [this project](https://github.com/raphink/geneve_1564/) ([dowload zip](https://github.com/raphink/geneve_1564/zipball/master)) be compiled?

I use TeXLive 2011 and texmakerx22b12_win32 for editing.

I have found it in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) post.

Comment: Please make this question more specific. What happens when you try to compile the document?

Comment: As the post says: It had been created with xetex (xelatex).

Comment: One error is: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function }. And every now and says he does not find the log file.. I have see "It had been created with xetex (xelatex)" but i'm new latex user and I have no idea how to set it.

Comment: In TeXstudio, try going to *User--> User commands --> Edit User commands*, write e.g. XeLaTeX as "menu item", and add `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` in the command field. Compile the document with this, i.e. *User --> User commands --> XeLaTeX*.

Comment: Thanks! i go to try. Also i need this https://github.com/downloads/georgd/EB-Garamond/EBGaramond-0.014c.zip font, right? one times that i have downloaded where i must put it?

Comment: Yes, you need to install the EB Garamond font. You're using Windows right? Download the zip-file, unpack it, and look inside the *otf* folder. Select all the files, right click and click *Install* (this works for Vista and W7, if you're on XP, copy the `.otf` files to *C:\Windows\fonts*).

Comment: ok it work but this is the results: http://www25.zippyshare.com/v/35707730/file.html

Comment: {\spacedfont\emph{\textsc{hallo}}} command for example why don't work?

Comment: Didn't see your comment until now (other users are notified unless you write @<username> in the comment). I get the same result, but I'm afraid I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 4):

Some time ago, I switched to LuaTeX and added a Makefile, so what you need is:

- LuaTeX (preferably TeXLive 2012);
- The EB Garamond font from https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond.

Type `make` and it should work (you can open an issue on github if it doesn't, describing your issue).